# How do I define a typeDefs in a schema for the following response?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js, graphql-java, express-graphql

I am trying to define a typeDefs for the following response in graphql:

```
CompactRes={
  "Compact": [
    [
      0,
      1,
      2,
      3
    ],
    [
      4,
      5,
      6,
      [
        7,
        2.567
      ]
    ]]}
```

Here is my schema:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
type Compact{
compact:[[Float]]
  }
 type Query {
    response(count: ID!): Compact
  }
`;
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    response: (parent, args, context, info) =>{
      return CompactRes;
        },
     },
};
```

I'm getting the following error when I run this:

[image]

Comment: You don't have an array of arrays of floats, your floats can optionally be arrays themselves. `[ 7,  2.567 ]` is not a float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution , We can achieve it by Mutation and Scalar

```
const CompactRes={
  "Compact": [
    [
      0,
      1,
      2,
      3
    ],
    [
      4,
      5,
      6,
      [
        7,
        2.567
      ]
    ]]}
  
    const typeDefs = gql`
    scalar CompactType
    type Compact{
    compact:Mutation
      }
     type Query {
        response(count: ID!): Compact
      }
    type Mutation{
        getCompactResponse(count:ID):CompactType
    }
    `;
    const resolvers = {
      Query: {
        response: (parent, args, context, info) =>{
          return CompactRes;
            },
         },
      Mutation:{
        getCompactResponse(_,{input}){
          return compactResponse;
        }
      },
    };
```

[image: Output here]